# Dynamic range Nth occurence Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have a table in Excel for which I would like to calculate average goals scored for `n` recent games with criteria being the team.

```
       Team         Score

         Real            4
         Real            4
         Barca           2
         Real            3
         Barca           2
         Real            3
         Barca           2
```

The problem is how to get the range dynamic in the `averageif` formula. A solution for the range could be `=$B$2:ROW (` where the row() input should be e.g. the 3rd occurrence of "Real"

How can I solve this without VBA?

Comment: So you want to put `Real` in one cell and `3` in another and average the first 3 scores for `Real`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$3:INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)))/($A$3:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A))=$D$2),E2)),$D$2,$B$3:INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)))/($A$3:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A))=$D$2),E2)))
```

It will average the score based on the two inputs, team and occurrence.

[image]

Comment: Magic, it works! Thank you.

questions is just how... :)

Answer (score 0):

Append a calculation sheet, from which you read the ranges. Make those cells protected after write so it's not immediately editable by the user.